# Formatting a phone number in a form using jquery

Tags: jquery, onfocus

I am attempting to format a phone number in a form input field using jquery, not sure what I am doing wrong....

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#phone').focusout(function() {

            function phoneFormat(phone) {
                phone = phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                phone = phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
                return phone;
            }

            var phone = $(this).text();
            phone = phoneFormat(phone);
            $(this).text(phone);
         });
});
```

Comment: Do you get an error or an unexpected result? What did you expect to get?

Comment: `not sure what I am doing wrong.` we are not sure too. Maybe you show what you expect and what really happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change this

```
var phone = $(this).text();
phone = phoneFormat(phone);
$(this).text(phone);
```

to

```
var phone = $(this).val();
phone = phoneFormat(phone);
$(this).val(phone);
```

because the value of an input field is retrieved and set using `val()` instead of `text()`.

```js
$('#phone').focusout(function() {

  function phoneFormat() {
    phone = phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    phone = phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
    return phone;
  }
  var phone = $(this).val();
  phone = phoneFormat(phone);
  $(this).val(phone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="phone" />
```