# Format billing phone number on WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, format, checkout

For the WooCommerce checkout billing field, how can I make this field require 9 numbers and insert dashes for proper phone formatting? For example, instead of typing out 3053453212 in the phone number field, it displays: (305-345-3212)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on "[Formatting a phone number in a form using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805961/formatting-a-phone-number-in-a-form-using-jquery)" answer code, here is the way to format the Woocommerce billing phone:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'format_checkout_billing_phone');
function format_checkout_billing_phone() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('#billing_phone').on( 'input focusout', function() {
            var p = $(this).val();

            p = p.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            p = p.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
            $(this).val(p);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
/** 
*  Require 9 digit number. Format to 000-000-0000 at submission
*  stackoverflow/54700465
*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'wc_filter_phone', 10, 1 );
function wc_filter_phone( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['billing_phone']['min-lenght="9"'];
    $format_number = preg_replace("/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/", "$1-$2-$3", $address_fields);
    return $format_number;  
}

// End
```

Comment: No luck :( I'm really thankful for attempting at this though

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that worked for me [is given here](https://joegrom.com/format-billing-phone-number-on-woocommerce/).

```
$_POST['billing_phone'] = preg_replace("/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/", "$1-$2-$3", $number);
```